# Is there a function for number parsing which works on iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, string-parsing, iterator-range

Is there a way in C++ or Boost to parse a number (`unsigned long long`, if possible) which works directly on `wstring` iterators? It should be as fast as `std::stoull`.

Comment: A simple loop will do.   Set result to `0ULL`.  Check if iterator references a digit.    If it does, multiply result by `10`, map the digits `'0'` to `'9'` to the range `0` to `9`, and add to result.   Increment iterator.   Repeat until non-digit or end iterator reached.   If that is done in a function, it will probably be no more than 5 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) has an [iterator-based API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/iterator_api.html). From what I've read it should be even faster than the standard string conversion functions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    std::wstring s(L"4398046511104");

    unsigned long long n = 0;
    qi::parse( begin(s), end(s), qi::ulong_long, n );

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24a6c1c0e9fa0207)